# Partial coloring of text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way in matplotlib to partially specify the color of a string?

Example:

```
plt.ylabel("Today is cloudy.")
```

How can I show "today" as red, "is" as green and "cloudy." as blue?

Comment: I think you would have to hack it with 3 separate text boxes.

Comment: Ask on matplotlib mailing list. It might be possible with custom renderer or "Artist" perhaps.

Comment: Also at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/697

Answer (score 34):

I only know how to do this non-interactively, and even then only with the 'PS' backend.

To do this, I would use Latex to format the text. Then I would include the 'color' package, and set your colors as you wish.

Here is an example of doing this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble='\usepackage{color}')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.ylabel(r'\textcolor{red}{Today} '+
           r'\textcolor{green}{is} '+
           r'\textcolor{blue}{cloudy.}')
plt.savefig('test.ps')
```

This results in (converted from ps to png using ImageMagick, so I could post it here):
[image]

Comment: I would use this one, if only it were to work with the PDF backend :) For some reason, I can never get the axes placed properly on the canvas while I am working with the ps backend.

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't mean to downvote this. I meant to upvote it, and I must have misclicked earlier.

Comment: Very nice solution. Is there a way to create`pdf`'s? Aside from saving it as `ps` and then `ps2pdf`, which pretty much screws up everything in my graph...

Comment: What a simple solution to this problem. If only it worked with more backends!

Comment: Is it possible that this doesn't work anymore with newer versions of matplotlib (>=v3.0)? When I try this it doesn't change colours but displaces the yticklabels...

Comment: With matplotlib 3.2.2 in py3, I had to escape the `\u` for unicode in  `'\usepackage{color}'`. Then, I got `type1ec.sty' not found` error,,even after installing `texlive-extra`.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Zaus. All yticklabels get displaced randomly.

Comment: This also helps if you want to get the coordinates of the ends of a string for plotting different strings individually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538620/matplotlib-calculate-axis-coordinate-extents-given-string

Comment: @user989761 - See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16911 - On Debian and derivatives: `sudo apt install cm-super` - on macOS: `sudo tlmgr install cm-super` - on other systems: see packages listed at https://repology.org/projects/?search=cmsuper or https://repology.org/projects/?search=cm-super or https://repology.org/projects/?search=fontsrecommended

Comment: This caused a runtime error for me when using Google Colab (not sure if it's their fault or if this code is broken). See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2589) for more

Comment: It looks like this works only on the `PS` backend and only saving to a file

Answer (score 29):

Here's the interactive version. **Edit:** Fixed bug producing extra spaces in Matplotlib 3.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms

def rainbow_text(x,y,ls,lc,**kw):
    """
    Take a list of strings ``ls`` and colors ``lc`` and place them next to each
    other, with text ls[i] being shown in color lc[i].

    This example shows how to do both vertical and horizontal text, and will
    pass all keyword arguments to plt.text, so you can set the font size,
    family, etc.
    """
    t = plt.gca().transData
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.show()

    #horizontal version
    for s,c in zip(ls,lc):
        text = plt.text(x,y,s+" ",color=c, transform=t, **kw)
        text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
        ex = text.get_window_extent()
        t = transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, x=ex.width, units='dots')

    #vertical version
    for s,c in zip(ls,lc):
        text = plt.text(x,y,s+" ",color=c, transform=t,
                rotation=90,va='bottom',ha='center',**kw)
        text.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
        ex = text.get_window_extent()
        t = transforms.offset_copy(text._transform, y=ex.height, units='dots')


plt.figure()
rainbow_text(0.05,0.05,"all unicorns poop rainbows ! ! !".split(), 
        ['red', 'orange', 'brown', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'black'],
        size=20)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the words aren't exactly aligned in the vertical version.

Comment: This was actually a bug in matplotlib at the time I wrote that comment. It has since been fixed, as you can see [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html).

Comment: Note that a figure does not necessarily have a canvas. E.g. in an object oriented setup, where a figure subclass might not be created with plt.figure()..

Comment: Phenomenal solution

Comment: very helpful, just a small comment, if you save the figure with a different dpi, the renderer gives back the wrong scaling, so to make this work you need the dpi to be set before calling the rainbow_text function

Answer (score 11):

Extending Yann's answer, LaTeX coloring now [also works with PDF export](http://www.futurile.net/2016/03/14/partial-colouring-text-in-matplotlib-with-latex/):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import FigureCanvasPgf
matplotlib.backend_bases.register_backend('pdf', FigureCanvasPgf)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pgf_with_latex = {
    "text.usetex": True,            # use LaTeX to write all text
    "pgf.rcfonts": False,           # Ignore Matplotlibrc
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r'\usepackage{color}'     # xcolor for colours
    ]
}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)

plt.figure()
plt.ylabel(r'\textcolor{red}{Today} '+
           r'\textcolor{green}{is} '+
           r'\textcolor{blue}{cloudy.}')
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

Note that this python script sometimes fails with `Undefined control sequence` errors in the first attempt. Running it again is then successful.

Comment: This does no longer work. Could you have a look perhaps if anything needs to be changed?

Comment: Figured out. We now need to include `backend='pgf'` in `savefig()` options.

Comment: Key pgf.preamble: Could not convert ['\\usepackage{color}'] to str

Answer (score 2):

After trying all the methods above, I return back to my stupid but easy method, using `plt.text`. The only problem is that you need to adjust the spaces between each word. You may need to adjust the positions several times, but I still like this way, because it

1. saves you from installing tex compilers,
2. does not require any special backends, and
3. free you from configuring matplotlib rc and configure back, or it may slows down your other plots, due to usetex=True

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
label_x = -0.15
ax.text(label_x, 0.35, r"Today", color='red', rotation='vertical', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(label_x, 0.5, r"is", color='green', rotation='vertical', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(label_x, 0.55, r"cloudy", color='blue', rotation='vertical', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]