# How to place text above hatched zone using matplotlib?

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

How to place text above hatched zone using matplotlib?
An example is shown below.
[image]
Below are my sample code for easy understanding

```
from pylab import *
fig=figure()
x=array([0,1])
yc=array([0.55,0.48])


yhc=array([0.55,0.68])

yagg=array([0.45,0.48])

plot(x,yc,'k-',linewidth=1.5)
plot(x,yhc,'k-',linewidth=1.5)
plot(x,yagg,'k-',linewidth=1.5)

xticks(fontsize = 22)
yticks(fontsize = 22)
ylim(0,1)
ax=axes()


p=fill_between(x, yc, yhc,color="none")

from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch 
for path in p.get_paths(): 
    p1 = PathPatch(path, fc="none", hatch="/") 
    ax.add_patch(p1) 
    p1.set_zorder(p.get_zorder()-0.1) 

props = dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='white', alpha=1,frameon='false')
text(0.6, 0.55, 'hi',fontsize=22)
fig.savefig('vp.png', transparent=True,bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

The hatched zone really makes it hard to see the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the `text` command a bounding box (`bbox`) that has its own background. Here's a simple change:

```
text(0.6, 0.55, 'hi',fontsize=22, bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.9, ))
```

which alters your example plot like so:

[image]

if you look up bboxes, you can figure out how to turn off the border around the bbox, if it conflicts with your hatching. Or make it a roundrec, etc etc. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086847/box-around-text-in-matplotlib) of various text-bounding-box styles.

Comment: Thanks, however if you do this way, can you remove the frame of the box? Or there is no choose, you have to accept it?

Comment: `text(0.6, 0.55, 'hi',fontsize=22, bbox=dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='none',
     alpha=0.9, ))
` will have no visible frame.