# How do I make the width of the title box span the entire plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

consider the following pandas series `s` and plot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(.001, .01, 100))
ax = s.cumprod().plot()
ax.set_title('My Log Normal Example', position=(.5, 1.02),
             backgroundcolor='black', color='white')
```

[image]

How do I get the box that contains the title to span the entire plot?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is setting it manually. Let's say, your `figsize=(9,7)`, then your title size, set manually: `size=40.5`. But, I would also be interested to find out if there is an other way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is, of course, possible to get the bounding box of the title, which is a `Text` element. This can be done with

```
title = ax.set_title(...) 
bb = title.get_bbox_patch()
```

In principle, one can then manipulate the bounding box, e.g. via 
`bb.set_width(...)`. However, all settings are lost, once matplotlib draws the title to the canvas. At least this is how I interpret the `Text`'s `draw()` method.

I'm not aware of other methods of setting the bounding box. For example a `legend`'s bounding box can be set via
`plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, mode="expand")` such that it expands over the full axes range (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location)). It would be very useful to have the same option for `Text` as well. But as for now, we don't.

The `Text` object allows setting a [`bbox`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) argument which is normally meant for setting the style of the bounding box. There is no way to set the bounding box extents, but it accepts some dictionary of properties of the surrounding box. And one of the accepted properties is a [`boxstyle`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#annotating-axes). Per default, this is a `square`, but can be set to a circle or arrow or other strange shapes.

Those `boxstyle`s are actually the key to a possible solution. They all inherit from `BoxStyle._Base` and - as can be seen at [the bottom of the annotations guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#define-custom-boxstyle) - one can define a custom shape, subclassing `BoxStyle._Base`.

**The following solution is based on subclassing `BoxStyle._Base` in a way that it accepts the width of the axes as an argument and draws the title's rectangle path such that it has exactly this width.**

As a bonus, we can register an event handler such that this width, once it changes due to resizing of the window, is adapted.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle


class ExtendedTextBox(BoxStyle._Base):
    """
    An Extended Text Box that expands to the axes limits 
                        if set in the middle of the axes
    """

    def __init__(self, pad=0.3, width=500.):
        """
        width: 
            width of the textbox. 
            Use `ax.get_window_extent().width` 
                   to get the width of the axes.
        pad: 
            amount of padding (in vertical direction only)
        """
        self.width=width
        self.pad = pad
        super(ExtendedTextBox, self).__init__()

    def transmute(self, x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size):
        """
        x0 and y0 are the lower left corner of original text box
        They are set automatically by matplotlib
        """
        # padding
        pad = mutation_size * self.pad

        # we add the padding only to the box height
        height = height + 2.*pad
        # boundary of the padded box
        y0 = y0 - pad
        y1 = y0 + height
        _x0 = x0
        x0 = _x0 +width /2. - self.width/2.
        x1 = _x0 +width /2. + self.width/2.

        cp = [(x0, y0),
              (x1, y0), (x1, y1), (x0, y1),
              (x0, y0)]

        com = [Path.MOVETO,
               Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO,
               Path.CLOSEPOLY]

        path = Path(cp, com)

        return path

dpi = 80

# register the custom style
BoxStyle._style_list["ext"] = ExtendedTextBox

plt.figure(dpi=dpi)
s = pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(.001, .01, 100))
ax = s.cumprod().plot()
# set the title position to the horizontal center (0.5) of the axes
title = ax.set_title('My Log Normal Example', position=(.5, 1.02), 
             backgroundcolor='black', color='white')
# set the box style of the title text box toour custom box
bb = title.get_bbox_patch()
# use the axes' width as width of the text box
bb.set_boxstyle("ext", pad=0.4, width=ax.get_window_extent().width )


# Optionally: use eventhandler to resize the title box, in case the window is resized
def on_resize(event):
    print "resize"
    bb.set_boxstyle("ext", pad=0.4, width=ax.get_window_extent().width )

cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', on_resize)

# use the same dpi for saving to file as for plotting on screen
plt.savefig(__file__+".png", dpi=dpi)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Just in case someone is interested in a lighter solution, there is also the option to play around with the `mutation_aspect` of the title's bounding box, which is apparently left unchanged when drawing the title. While the `mutation_aspect` itself basically only changes the height of the box, one can use extremely large padding for the box and set `mutation_aspect` to a very small number such that at the end the box appears extended in width. The clear drawback of this solution is, that the values for the padding and aspect have to be found by trial and error and will change for different font and figure sizes.
In my case, the values of `mutation_aspect = 0.04` and `pad=11.9` produce the desired result, but on other systems, they may, of course, be different.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(.001, .01, 100))
ax = s.cumprod().plot()
title = ax.set_title('My Log Normal Example', position=(.5, 1.02),
             backgroundcolor='black', color='white',
             verticalalignment="bottom", horizontalalignment="center")
title._bbox_patch._mutation_aspect = 0.04
title.get_bbox_patch().set_boxstyle("square", pad=11.9)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the bounty ended today and good solutions take a while to be typed in. ;-)

Comment: I started a new bounty.  It will be yours, almost certainly, in 24 hours.  Unless someone else comes in with a better answer (I doubt it, but possible).

Answer (score 21):

Instead of scaling the bounding box of the title text itself, you can create a secondary axis above the primary one and use it as a "box" for your title. As axes normally don't look as boxes, we'll switch off its axes labels and ticks, and will set the background color to black to match the OP.

I'm using the same approach to make a secondary, matching, axis as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195921/4118756).

Additionally, I've used `AnchoredText` to snap the title text to the axis so that it can easily be located in the center of it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(.001, .01, 100))
ax = s.cumprod().plot()

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="11%", pad=0)
cax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
cax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
cax.set_facecolor('black')

at = AnchoredText("My Log Normal Example", loc=10,
                  prop=dict(backgroundcolor='black',
                            size=12, color='white'))
cax.add_artist(at)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:** for older `matplotlib` versions you might need to switch to `cax.set_axis_bgcolor('black')` when setting the background color.

Comment: You said, "instead of scaling the bounding box of the title text itself...". Would you know a way to actually solve this problem by setting the bounding box of a `Text`. Does this option even exist?

Comment: I imagine one would have to tinker with the padding of the bounding box. The problem is that it is scaled by a scalar value uniformly in all directions. There might be a way to set large padding in horizontal direction only ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249489/side-specific-padding-for-matplotlib-text-bbox) looks promising), but I have not looked into it.

Comment: Well... no one can give me a better answer and this is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

piRSquared's answer is great!
But using the Class ExtendedTextBox may cause python's warning: "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The transmute method was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later."
I find some new ways to Custom box styles! (ref:https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/custom_boxstyle01.html?highlight=boxstyle+_style_list)
Let me re-write the Class ExtendedTextBox without a python warning:

```
class ExtendedTextBox_v2:
    """
    制作自己的box类，以提供调整width功能
    参考：
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796117/how-do-i-make-the-width-of-the-title-box-span-the-entire-plot
    https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/custom_boxstyle01.html?highlight=boxstyle+_style_list
    """

    def __init__(self, pad=0.3, width=500.):
        """
        The arguments must be floats and have default values.

        Parameters
        ----------
        pad : float
            amount of padding
        """
        self.width = width
        self.pad = pad
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size):
        """
        Given the location and size of the box, return the path of the box
        around it.

        Rotation is automatically taken care of.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x0, y0, width, height : float
            Box location and size.
        mutation_size : float
            Reference scale for the mutation, typically the text font size.
        """
        # padding
        pad = mutation_size * self.pad
        # width and height with padding added
        #width = width + 2.*pad
        height = height + 2.*pad
        # boundary of the padded box
        y0 = y0 - pad
        y1 = y0 + height
        _x0 = x0
        x0 = _x0 +width /2. - self.width/2.
        x1 = _x0 +width /2. + self.width/2.
        # return the new path
        return Path([(x0, y0),
                     (x1, y0), (x1, y1), (x0, y1),
                     (x0, y0)],
                    closed=True)
```