# Matplotlib add signature bar at the bottom of figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a signature bar at the bottom of a figure. I would like to be able to do it without all the manual labor of playing with text x and y values and adding empty strings. I was thinking about using annotate but I'm having a couple of issues:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_xlabel('Angle')

ax.annotate('What what?', xy=(0, 0), xycoords='figure fraction',backgroundcolor = 'blue')
```

My main issues:
1. I want the bar to go across the whole width of the figure. I can add blank text to extend the bar but I was hoping for something automated so I don't have to do it manually for different scenarios. 
2. I want to move the bar a little lower without the bar disappearing or cropping it.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: What exactly is a "signature bar"? Can be more precise of what the desired output is?

Comment: By signature bar I mean some box that extends the whole width of the figure either at the bottom or the top where I can write my name and the data source. Fivethirtyeight figures are an example of such "signature bars". For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=fivethirtyeight+figures&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR0Z_1kd_XAhVh1oMKHeZFDKAQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1536&bih=686#imgrc=PE5bdnXx75n8UM:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to adjust the bounding box of  a text. An option to do so is shown in this question: [How do I make the width of the title box span the entire plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796117/how-do-i-make-the-width-of-the-title-box-span-the-entire-plot)

Trying to avoid this, a simpler, but less automatic solution would be to create a rectangle in the lower part of the figure and add some text, such that it looks like the text sits in the rectangle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_xlabel('Angle')


def signaturebar(fig,text,fontsize=10,pad=5,xpos=20,ypos=7.5,
                 rect_kw = {"facecolor":"grey", "edgecolor":None},
                 text_kw = {"color":"w"}):
    w,h = fig.get_size_inches()
    height = ((fontsize+2*pad)/72.)/h
    rect = plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,height, transform=fig.transFigure, clip_on=False,**rect_kw)
    fig.axes[0].add_patch(rect)
    fig.text(xpos/72./h, ypos/72./h, text,fontsize=fontsize,**text_kw)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=fig.subplotpars.bottom+height)

signaturebar(fig,"This is my signature text")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Can you please explain the 72. What are the units of fontsize? Thanks!

Comment: Units are points. Matplotlib uses 72 points per inch (ppi). E.g. to calculate pixels from points you would need the figure dpi `pixels = fig.dpi/72.` Because the answer uses points as units and positions in figure coordinates it would be independent on the figure dpi.