# How to change the background color in matplotplot title?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

This pic is plot by R, and what I want to know is how do it with matplotlib.
I have tried the `plt.title('aaa', backgroundcolor= 'silver')`, but it only change the background color where the text cover.

[image]

So any methods to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'silver'
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected.  The linked duplicate provides a better answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796117/how-do-i-make-the-width-of-the-title-box-span-the-entire-plot