# Set Latex greek letter in plotting script using matplotlib

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, latex, symbols

I have a plotting script where I load subtitles (variable `subplot_titles`) from a JSON file :

example of JSON file :

```
"subplot_titles" : {

    "0" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - optimistic - No $\\gamma$",
    "1" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - optimistic - With $\\gamma$",
    "2" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - semi-pessimistic - No $\\gamma$",
    "3" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - semi-pessimistic - With $\\gamma$"
},
```

In my script, I load this file like this :

```
 for i, ax in enumerate(np.ravel(axes)):

    config = load_config('./config.json')

    df = parse_input(config['subplot_files'][i])
    df = format_dataframe(df, config)
    title = config['subplot_titles'][i]
    lgd = plot_barchart(df, ax, title)
    bbea.append(lgd)
```

But once the figure is generated, I have an uggly symbol "gamma", like this :

[image: bad gamma]

I would like to display a Latex gamma symbol.

I tried to add `r'` in the plotting script to get Latex support :

```
title = config[r'subplot_titles'][i]
```

But I get an error.

What can I do to get this gamma greek symbol under Latex displaying ?

### Update

The solutions given works but I want to keep the matplotlib font for legend which appears under the form in jSON file :

```
"bars" : {

    "0" : "$GC_{s}$",
    "1" : "$GC_{ph} + WL$",
    "2" : "$GC_{s} + GC_{ph} + WL$",
    "3" : "$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$",
    "4" : "$GC_{s} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$",
    "5" : "($GC_{s} + GC_{ph} + WL) + XC2$",
    "6" : "$GC_{s} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC) + XC2$"

},
```

that produces a nice legend :

[image: wanted result]

For the `subplot_titles`, **I have just to replace a greek symbol by the Latex equivalent but caution, with the real Latex symbol \gamma**, not the one which makes part of Latex of matplotlib like the ugly "\gamma" symbol I have shown above, and keep all the rest as it is currently.

I tried to make this subsitution :

```
title = title.replace("\\gamma", "+r\"\\mathit{\\gamma}")
```

but without success. How to perform this rendering ?

Comment: Unless you want to create a ransom letter, pick one font for which you like both text and math symbols. Don't mix serif math with sans-serif text.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How do you mean "ransom letter"?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransom_note_effect

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ha! I didn't know it was an official typography term. I thought you trying to encourage OP in illegal activities.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin The contrary! I am trying to prevent a crime against typography :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change matplotlib rc settings to use LaTeX, for example by including the following code before you start plotting:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

Alternatively, instead of using LaTeX you can just change the font that matplotlib is using to typeset mathematics:

```
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'
```

`'cm'` is Computer Modern, the default LaTeX font, but there are also [other possibilities](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#fonts).

If you want to fine-tune font selection, LaTeX will be probably a better option. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"]  = r"\usepackage{cmbright}"

plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
plt.title(r"$w_{0},w_{a}$ - flat - optimistic - with $\gamma$")
plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], 'r-', label=r"$GC_s$")
plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 1], 'b--', label=r"$GC_{ph} + WL$")
plt.plot([1, 2], [2, 0], 'g-.', label=r"$GC_s + GC_{ph} + WL$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. How to do only the modification to have a Latex symbol \gamma while keeping the other default font of matplotlib for the rest ?

Comment: Thanks but this syntax can't be applied to JSON file which is under the form :

`"subplot_titles" : {

    "0" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - optimistic - No $\\gamma$",
    "1" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - optimistic - With $\\gamma$",
    "2" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - semi-pessimistic - No $\\gamma$",
    "3" : "Model: $~w_{0},~w_{a}~$ - flat - semi-pessimistic - With $\\gamma$"
},`

Comment: @youpilat13 Once you read each title from the JSON file, you can modify it before using it in the plot - `title = title.replace("\\gamma", "\\mathit{\\gamma}")` etc.

Comment: But I am obliged to put `mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'`  to get the Latex Gamma symbol and this affect all the legend here https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2yLf.png whereas I want to keep the default matplotlib font for legend. How to circumevent this issue ? I jus want only to insert one greek Latex symbol (real Latex font)

Comment: .You don't see a solution for my special issue ?

Comment: It is not straightforward to change the font of a single character.  I added though an example of how you can fine-tune font selection using LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay a second `Axes` on top of the first one, make all labels and spines invisible in order to use this axes only for the "gamma"-part of the title. Then the original axes' title will be the actual title without the `\gamma` and the second axes' title will only contain `\gamma` and receive the desired math font family (e.g. `'cm'`). The difficult part is to align the two titles such that the second one is position next to the first one. In the following example I hardcoded the positions, so this will only work for the given figure size. I didn't find a way to make it automatically adjust, but answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796117/3767239) might be helpful in further exploring that option.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))
ax.set_title(r"$w_{0},w_{a}$ - flat - optimistic - with ", position=(0.5, 1.0))

newax = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position())
newax.patch.set_visible(False)
newax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
newax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
newax.set_title(r'$\gamma$', position=(0.845, 1.0)).set_math_fontfamily('cm')

ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], 'r-', label=r"$GC_s$")
ax.plot([1, 2], [3, 1], 'b--', label=r"$GC_{ph} + WL$")
ax.plot([1, 2], [2, 0], 'g-.', label=r"$GC_s + GC_{ph} + WL$")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Example plot]