# How to draw rectangle outside of the plot frame in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, visualization

I want to generate the subfigure's title in the style of followed figure:

[image]

A gray box should be beneath the title which are at the top of the scatter point.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
x = random.sample(range(50), 50)
y= random.sample(range(50), 50)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y,label='a')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,60)
ax.set_ylim(0,60)
ax.plot([0,60], [0, 60], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.25)

ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0,60),60, 10,facecolor='silver',linewidth = 0))
TITLE = ax.text(26,61, r'$\mathregular{Title}$',fontsize = 14,zorder = 5,color = 'k')
```

The result show like:

[image]

> The rectangle as the background box of title can't be shown in my result

Any advice or better solution are appreciate!

Comment: This is a "blind" try. If 10 is a positive height, why not to start with (0,50) as a origin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think a better way is to use the **clip_on=False** option for [Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

x = random.sample(range(50), 50)
y= random.sample(range(50), 50)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y,label='a')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,60)
ax.set_ylim(0,60)
ax.plot([0,60], [0, 60], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.25)

ax.add_patch(pyplot.Rectangle((0,60),60, 10,facecolor='silver',
                              clip_on=False,linewidth = 0))
TITLE = ax.text(26,61, r'$\mathregular{Title}$',fontsize = 14,zorder = 5,
                color = 'k')
pyplot.show()
```

This yields a rectangle drawn outside of the axes, without having to resort to extra spaces:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0,60),60, 10,facecolor='silver',linewidth = 0))
```

And change the last line by adding `bbox`:

```
TITLE = ax.text(26,62, 'Title',fontsize = 14,zorder = 6, color = 'k',
                bbox={'facecolor':'silver', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':4})
```

[image: bbox_example]

The only way I found to give it an arbitrary length is to add blank spaces.

```
TITLE = ax.text(1,62, '                     Title                    ',
                fontsize = 14,zorder = 6,color = 'k', 
                bbox={'facecolor':'silver', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':4})
```

[image: bbox_example_2]

For more info on bbox see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086847/box-around-text-in-matplotlib) in SO.