# Create a rectangle outside of the axes limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, rectangles, axes

Using python, I want to place a small square on figure that I have. I am trying to do that using matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.

My problem is that I want it to appear outside the axes of the figure. So say my y axis runs from 0 to 100, I want my square to appear at, say, 110.

But currently, I create my rectangle (there are actually multiple), then create a PatchCollection object and finally add it to the axis:

ax.add_collection(my_collection).

So because this is an axis object, it doesn't make sense to ask the rectangle to appear outside the range of the axis. The code runs, but the rectangles are never visible (or maybe I can just see the edges peeking out if I want it to appear at a y axis of, say 95):

[image]

How can I place a rectangle that will appear outside the axes. Do I have to create another set of axes or something like that?

Comment: It would be best to post a minimal reproducible question with some code.

Comment: First add your rectangle, then redefine the range of your yaxis using [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)

Comment: I don't see how changing my ylim will help. Either the rectangle will be inside my axes (which I don't want - I want it outside the axes), or the rectangle will not be visible.

Comment: I can try to add a mwe later if it helps.

Comment: Do you want the rectangle to be defined in data coordinates? Or maybe rather in coordinates relative to the axes?

Comment: @user1551817 you mean having a rectangle outside the **plot**? something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469207/how-to-draw-rectangle-outside-of-the-plot-frame-in-matplotlib)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `addpatch`:

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((xpos, ypos), width, height,
                               facecolor='green', clip_on=False))
```

and set xpos, ypos, width and height to your desired values

Comment: If you can edit this to say that "clip_on=False" is required -  as in the link you provided in your comment to the original question - I can accept this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: added clip_on=False