# how to draw a rectangle over a matplotlib figure, also overlaying the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a rectangle over a matplotlib figure, in a way that allows overlaying the axes.

The answers I found online only allow drawing a rectange inside the axes, but not overlaying them.
**EDIT**: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469207/how-to-draw-rectangle-outside-of-the-plot-frame-in-matplotlib) allows drawing outside the plot frame. However it does not overlay the axis. Namely, the axis is kept visible. See the example where the axis is still visible behind the red rectangle

[image]

See an example below for what I wish to achieve (Code for the bar plot can be taken from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html). For the example, the figure was edited with a simple paint software).
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is drawn  via matplotlib.pyplot.hist() function in matplotlib