# Matplotlib - Multicolour axis labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, label, axis

Morning all,
I have 2 bar charts which relate to the same y-axis.  The grey bar chart represents "idle time", and the blue bar chart represents "total time".  Currently the yaxis is labelled as "Idle Time & Total Time", I was wondering if it's possible to specify the word "Idle Time" in grey, and the word "Total Time" in blue.

I was reading the documentation for matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel and it doesn't appear, from my understanding anyway, that such a multicolour capacity exist within these parameters.

Also, if it isn't possible an awareness of a common 'work-around' would be grealy appreciated.

Thanks,

Kelly.

Comment: Is this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9185851/1643946) any use?