# how can I put an arrow near my x/ylabel?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Im working with matplotlib and I want an arrow beside my "axis-legend". But I have no idea how.
In the example, the arrows I want are drawn in red.
[image: example]
thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can generate arrows as shown in your example figure by using the [TeX renderer](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/mathtext.html) built into matplotlib.  Coloring is an option for the whole strings, although generating multiple colors in a single text string is more work.

This will give you the mathematical symbols plus the arrows (I've shown different lengths on each axis label):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# plot your data here ...

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\rho/\rho_{ref}\;\rightarrow$', color='red')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\Delta \Theta / \omega \longrightarrow$')

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Resulting in:

[image: .]

[Partial coloring of text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9169052/1643946) deals with multi-color strings, and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185143/1643946) describes how to use the latex engine with multiple colors.  However, it does not color what is rendered in the interactive graph, so it depends on your exact needs.

[More arrows in LaTeX math mode](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/MPWP/LATEXmath/node9.html)

Comment: oh... Im an idiot :D  I made the example myself, ofcourse using LaTex at the labels... but dont know why I didnt thought of the arrows from LaTex... thx a lot :D

Comment: no problem! don't forget that using raw strings is often needed for rendering latex (`r'\rho'` for example)