# How could an arrow drawn within xlabel/ylabel be scaled up/down in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246094/how-can-i-put-an-arrow-near-my-x-ylabel/22246808#22246808), generation of an arrow within xlabel/ylabel was explained. The explanation provides an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# plot your data here ...

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\rho/\rho_{ref}\;\rightarrow$', color='red')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\Delta \Theta / \omega \longrightarrow$')

plt.show()
```

Resulting below:

[image: .]

How could one scale *only* arrow without scaling the text therein?

Comment: I will take this opportunity to advertise [this set of functions I wrote](https://github.com/saintsfan342000/MPL-a-al-SKK) to format matplotlib figures in a way that suit my advisor's tastes.  He also likes putting arrows on the axis labels.  I implemented them using the FancyArrow.  Have a look at the Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `LaTeX` to render the text (using `rcParams`), then you can use `LaTeX` size commands to change parts of the text. E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\rho/\rho_{ref} \;$ \Huge{$ \rightarrow $}', color='red')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\Delta \Theta / \omega $ \Huge{$\longrightarrow$}')

plt.show()
```

[image]