# matplotlib two different colors in the same annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure in python and make is so that the same annonate text will have two colors, half of the annonate will be blue and the other half will be red.

I think the code explain itself. I have 3 lines 1 green with green annonate, 1 blue with blue annonate.

The 3rd is red its the summation of plot 1 and plot 2, and I want it to have half annonate blue and half green.

ipython -pylab

```
x=arange(0,4,0.1)

exp1 = e**(-x/5)
exp2 = e**(-x/1)
exp3 = e**(-x/5) +e**(-x/1) 

figure()
plot(x,exp1)
plot(x,exp2)
plot(x,exp1+exp2)
title('Exponential Decay')


annotate(r'$e^{-x/5}$', xy=(x[10], exp1[10]), xytext=(-20,-35), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',color='blue',
          bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.95', 
                            color='b'))

annotate(r'$e^{-x/1}$', xy=(x[10], exp2[10]), xytext=(-5,20), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',color='green',
          bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=-0.5', 
                            color='g'))

annotate(r'$e^{-x/5} + e^{-x/1}$', xy=(x[10], exp2[10]+exp1[10]), xytext=(40,20), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',
          bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=-0.5', 
                            color='red'))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @bli Did you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: Thanks. This answer is indeed quite relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42768093/1878788

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `r'$\textcolor{blue}{e^{-x/5}} + \textcolor{green}{e^{-x/1}}$'` to make the text half blue, half green. Using your own code for example:

[image]

The image is generated by the following code. Testd with matplotlib v2.1.2 with the default `matplotlibrc` settings.

```
import matplotlib as matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pgf')
matplotlib.rc('pgf', texsystem='pdflatex')  # from running latex -v
preamble = matplotlib.rcParams.setdefault('pgf.preamble', [])
preamble.append(r'\usepackage{color}')

from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

x=arange(0,4,0.1)

exp1 = e**(-x/5)
exp2 = e**(-x/1)
exp3 = e**(-x/5) +e**(-x/1) 

figure()
plot(x,exp1)
plot(x,exp2)
plot(x,exp1+exp2)
title('Exponential Decay')


annotate(r'$e^{-x/5}$', xy=(x[10], exp1[10]), xytext=(-20,-25), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',color='blue',
         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.95', 
                            color='b'))

annotate(r'$e^{-x/1}$', xy=(x[10], exp2[10]), xytext=(25,20), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',color='green',
         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=-0.5', 
                            color='g'))

annotate(r'$\textcolor{blue}{e^{-x/5}} + \textcolor[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}{e^{-x/1}}$', 
         xy=(x[10], exp2[10]+exp1[10]), xytext=(40,20), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',
         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=-0.5', 
                            color='red'))

savefig('test.png')
```

It is mainly your code with the following changes:

1. You need to use a `pgf` backend.
2. Usepackage `color` in `pgf.preamble`
3. There's some overlapping with the 1st and 2nd annotations, so `xytext` is changed.
4. The `color='g'` in te 2nd annotation actually didn't use the pure "Green" color like (0, 255, 0) of rgb. `\textcolor[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}` makes it looking alike.

Comment: Thanks, this works. In my own case, I had memory problems with TeX, likely due to an important number of points to plot in a scatterplot. I solved the issue by using `"lualatex"` for `texsystem`.

Comment: @bli, Yes, that line of `matplotlib.rc('pgf', texsystem='pdflatex')` should be deleted. I think the default tex system also works.

Comment: Trying this in Jupyter, I get a warning `anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:14: UserWarning: matplotlib.pyplot as already been imported, this call will have no effect.` on the line `matplotlib.use('pgf')`. Then when I try use `\textcolor` I get the error `ValueError: 
\textcolor{blue}{e^{-x/5}} + \textcolor{green}{e^{-x/1}}
^
Unknown symbol: \textcolor (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)`. Any idea how to resolve this?
`

Comment: From the [matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html), `If you use the matplotlib.use() function, this must be done before importing matplotlib.pyplot. Calling use() after pyplot has been imported will have no effect.`

Comment: @gepcel I'm having this error: 

`ValueError: Error processing '\(\displaystyle \textcolor{blue}{e^{-x/5}} + \textcolor[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}{e^{-x/1}}\)'
LaTeX Output:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...lectfont \(\displaystyle \textcolor 
                                                  {blue}{e^{-x/5}} + \textco...
<*> ...\textcolor[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}{e^{-x/1}}\)}
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.`

Please help in resolving this as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @firnnauriel I can't be sure what the problem is with the error message. But the example code can't run with more current matplotlib versions (not sure since when). You can change line 3 to `matplotlib.rc('pgf', texsystem='pdflatex', preamble=r'\usepackage{color}')`, and delete line 4 and 5, and try again.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can have multiple colours in a single annotation, since—as far as I know—`annotate` only takes one text object as parameter, and text objects only support single colours. So, to my knowledge, there's no "native" or "elegant" way of automatically doing this.

There is, however, a workaround: you can have multiple text objects placed arbitrarily in the graph. So here's how I'd do it:

```
fig1 = figure()
# all the same until the last "annotate":
annotate(r'$e^{-x/5}$'+r'$e^{-x/1}$', xy=(x[10], exp2[10]+exp1[10]), xytext=(40,20), 
         textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom',color='white',
          bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3),
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=-0.5', 
                            color='r'))

fig1.text(0.365, 0.62, r'$e^{-x/5}$', ha="center", va="bottom", size="medium",color="blue")
fig1.text(0.412, 0.62, r'$e^{-x/1}$', ha="center", va="bottom", size="medium",color="green")
```

What I did was:

1. I set the annotation `color='black'`;
2. I created the two text objects at positions 0.5, 0.5 (which means the center of `fig1`);
3. I manually changed the positions until they were roughly overlapping with the black text generated by `annotate` (which ended up being the values you see in the two calls to `text`);
4. I set the annotation `color='white'`, so it doesn't interfere with the colour of the overlapping text.

Here's the output:

[image: multi-colour annotated graph]

It's not very elegant, and it does require some plotting to fine-tune the positions, but it gets the job done.

If you need several plots, perhaps there's a way to automate the placement: If you don't store the `fig1` object, the coordinates for `text` become the actual x,y coordinates in the graph—I find that a bit harder to work with, but maybe it'd enable you to generate them automatically using the annotation's `xy` coordinates? Doesn't sound worth the trouble for me, but if you make it happen, I'd like to see the code.

Comment: After plotting this I realised there's a `+` in your plot, which I didn't notice before. I'm sure the instructions are enough for you to plot it with an extra `text`.
Also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9185143/3540074), it provides a way more elegant way to do it, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2024 and matplotlib version `3.8.3`, here is a minimal example following the comment of user kadu.

```py
import matplotlib as matplotlib

matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rc("pgf", texsystem="pdflatex", preamble=r"\usepackage{color}")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
ax.scatter([1, 2], [1, 2])
ax.set_xticks([1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels([r"\textcolor{blue}{blue} + \textcolor{green}{green}", "b"])
plt.annotate(
    r"$e^{-x/5}$",
    xy=(1.5, 1.5),
    xytext=(-20, -25),
    textcoords="offset points",
    ha="center",
    va="bottom",
    color="blue",
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.2", fc="yellow", alpha=0.3),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.95", color="b"),
)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("/tmp/out.pdf")
```

[image]