# Different colors for characters of the same data label in a Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set different colors (e.g. #0088BC and #FF8B00) for each letter (or group of characters) for the label of one data series in a Python plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can have different colors for different letters in the same label. You might try this workaround here:
[matplotlib two different colors in the same annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108063/matplotlib-two-different-colors-in-the-same-annotate)

Comment: It seems like you're right, there is no way to have different colors for different characters in a label since it's a text object. I guess I have to do it the manual and complicated way...

Answer (score 1):

not sure it is exactly what you want to do, but in matplotlib you can customize whatever you want, as well as the label color,

Example :

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rc("axes", labelcolor="r")
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.xlabel("xlabel")
plt.show()
```

Check [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for more customization.

Comment: I wanted to change the color for every character of one label, this changes it for all of them.  Thank you for the effort though! :)