# Colored LaTeX labels in plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am trying to make the x-label colored, but I have no idea how to establish that. The difficulty is that I want to use LaTeX font and the package "amsmath".

My code is:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x,y=np.random.rand(20),np.random.rand(20)


plt.figure()

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]


plt.plot(x,y,'.')




plt.xlabel(r'$x=\frac{\text{red}}{\text{blue}}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')

#plt.savefig('colored_labels.png')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anyone have a trick how to make the x-axis in the pronounced colors?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want the whole thing coloured some colour or do you want the "red" red and the "blue" blue?

Comment: I would like to have the "red" red and "blue" blue

Comment: Check this out: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I looked at the questions you posted above already, the problem is here that I want to use Latex font.. and here I somehow can't manage colored labels

Comment: Look at the question linked by The Dude, it should answer your question.

Comment: When using Latex to show colors in fonts, whether or not the colors show up depends on the matplotlib backend.  I don't know the survey of which backends work and which don't, but it would be useful if someone compiled a list of these since this question comes up frequently.

Comment: I've looked at the question linked by The Dude, particularily the second answer there and now I tried to use the postscript-backend, but I get a "RuntimeError: ghostscript was not able to process your image .."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here might be in the Latex regime.
Your command `\text` is a Latex-command present in amsmath to set text as such in equations. It does not provide any colors.

Without having tried it myself in Python, I would suggest you try loading xcolor in Latex as well:

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{xcolor}"]
```

Then you'll be able to use xcolors' `\color`-command:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$x=\frac{ \color{red}{red text} }{ \color{blue}{blue text} }$')
```

Again, untested in Python, but you might even get better results using the `\text`-command on top of this:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$x=\frac{ \text{\color{red}{red text}} }{ \text{\color{blue}{blue text}} }$')
```

At least the Latex-part of this code works and gives you the desired results.

Let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: thanks, but it's still not colored... seems that python is not compatible with colored LaTeX fonts?!

Comment: It looks that way, yes. Based on a quick google search I would think it depends on the backend used, it might be possible to get colored fonts in ps-output. But I lost the source of that information.