# Colored underlined label in matplotlib with pdf backend

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I try to color underlay the axis labels in `matplotlib` and create a `pdf` from it. Something like this

[image: example]

I tried the following

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{xcolor}']

_, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 2], 'b')

ax.set_ylabel( \
r'{\colorlet{temp}{.}\color{red}\underline{\color{temp}{A}}\color{temp}},' +
r'{\colorlet{temp}{.}\color{blue}\underline{\color{temp}{B}}\color{temp}}' +
' (m)')

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.savefig('test.ps')

plt.show()
```

which works fine for the `ps` but not the `pdf` (The labels are still black). Unfortunatelly `ps2pdf` screws up other parts of my plot so I cannot use it.

Related:
[Partial coloring of text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib)
Latex code from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/how-to-color-over-underline-or-other-ways-to-highlight-substituted-expressions

Comment: Have you tried pdfPages? http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html

Comment: @YOBA. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out now. But unfortunately its still black and white