# Latex colors not rendered in matplotlib text

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Tex's `\textcolor` seems to be ignored in my plottling script

```
import matplotlib as matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True})

matplotlib.rc(
    'text.latex', preamble=r"\usepackage{xcolor}")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel(r'\textcolor{red}{aaaaaaa}')
plt.show()
```

does not give me a red text, it produces:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib)

Comment: In principle, matplotlib cannot colorize parts of a text differently; a workaround is shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in more detail here : https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html but seems like it only works when you export it to a ps file. For me, it works in color if you're saving it as a ps file while the same file inline doesn't work.

Slight workaround here.

```
import matplotlib as matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True})
matplotlib.rc('text.latex', preamble=r"\usepackage{xcolor}")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel(r"aaaaaaa", color='r')

#plt.savefig(r"foo.ps")
# you can include the above line if you're using your old code.

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it work in a more complicated code, involving an Animation that I save as gif. So saving to ps is not really I option unfortunately, I think.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem a lot of people had. Is it possible to use the method above to do it(which doesn't involve saving to ps i.e. using color='r') , or does the code involved something else ?

Comment: I am using this to color only a portion of the text so I don't think I can