# matplotlib multicolor text in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a multicolored text in a legend
I.e currently the legend text looks as:
[image]

But I would like it to look as
[image]

I tried using the multicolored [title example](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html) from matplotlib, But I think it only suits axis texts.

Comment: Yes, but the same strategy would need to be applied here, it will just be even more complicated. Though, depending on the application, you could also use latex as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LaTeX for this:

```
from matplotlib import rc, pyplot
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('text.latex', preamble='\usepackage{color}')
matplotlib.use('ps')

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s, label=r'\textcolor{red}{Hello} \textcolor{green}{color} \textcolor{blue}{legend}!')

pyplot.legend()
pyplot.savefig('test.ps')
```

[image]