# Coloring a string using latex in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to colour a string using latex in matplotlib and using the following code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble='\usepackage{color}')

plt.figure()
plt.ylabel(r'\textcolor{red}{Today} '+
           r'\textcolor{green}{is} '+
           r'\textcolor{blue}{cloudy.}')
```

But on executing the above code I am getting the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-38-6ffb8d156b19>", line 7
    rc('text.latex', preamble='\usepackage{color}')
                             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Does anyone know what should I add/update to the code to remove the error so that the code works perfectly as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` character in `preamble='\usepackage{color}'`. You have two options for this.

1. you can use a raw string:

   ```
   rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{color}')
   ```
2. you can escape the `\` in the string itself:

   ```
   rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage{color}')
   ```

   [image: enter code here]

Comment: Now the code is outputting the following error: `RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found`

Comment: That means you don't have latex installed on your sysyem