# Matplotlib custom bbox style with Underline + Facecolor possible?

Tags: matplotlib, text, path

Is it possible to define custom matpotlib boxstyles that look like these, eg. with a thick underline and a facecolor?

[image: html text style example 1]
[image: html text style example 2]

images from https://academy.datawrapper.de/article/190-how-to-turn-your-title-into-a-color-key

I managed the underline but if I only have this line as the returned path, facecolor won't have an effect.
Is it possible to return two combined paths for example?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle
from matplotlib.path import Path

def underline(x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size, mutation_aspect=1, pad=0.3):
    """
    Given the location and size of the box, return the path of the box around
    it.

    Rotation is automatically taken care of.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x0, y0, width, height : float
        Box location and size.
    mutation_size : float
        Mutation reference scale, typically the text font size.
    mutation_aspect
        Mutation aspect ratio.
    """
    # We ignore mutation_aspect. This is okay in general.

    x1 = x0 + width
    # return the new path
    return Path([(x0, y0),
                 (x1, y0)],
                closed=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "Test", size=30, va="center", ha="center",
        bbox=dict(boxstyle=underline))
```

Comment: Probably the approaches of [Partial coloring of text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib) can be extended.

Comment: This is actually what I am intending on using this for. I have written the highlight-text package https://github.com/znstrider/highlight_text which I am currently refactoring and aiming on extending a bit.