# How to fill colors of latex symbols in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want dimond to be filled with red, circle to filled with blue and star as green in the title. How to do that?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig,ax=plt.subplots( figsize=(4,5))
xx=[1,2,3,4,5]
yy=[3,2,4,5,1]
plt.plot(xx,yy)
name=r'$\bigtriangleup \bigcirc \bigstar \diamondsuit$'
plt.title(name)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See [Partial coloring of text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052/partial-coloring-of-text-in-matplotlib)

Comment: This cannot fill the color inside the circle and diamond.