# Matplotlib text: change the color of a single character

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, colors

Given an arbitrary text string `abcdRef` in blue color. Is there a sufferable way to turn the `R` into red color ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.0, 0.0, 'aaaaRaa',
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='center',  
        fontsize=50, 
        fontweight = 'bold',
        color='#000080'
        )
plt.axis("equal"); plt.show()
```

In the given example, the `R` should be red at the end.
[image]

Comment: There is the LaTeX approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185143/8881141

Comment: Thank you @Mr. T ! The LaTeX approach has resulted in system errors. But `def rainbow_text()` did work.